# Convert list of multiple strings into a Python data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of string values I read this from a text document with `splitlines`. which yields something like this

```
       X = ["NAME|Contact|Education","SMITH|12345|Graduate","NITA|11111|Diploma"]
```

I have tried this

```
for i in X:
    textnew = i.split("|")
    data[x] = textnew
```

I want to make a dataframe out of this

```
    Name     Contact      Education
    SMITH     12345        Graduate
    NITA      11111        Diploma
```

Comment: use `pd.read_csv("filename", sep="|")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read it directly from your file by specifying a `sep` argument to `pd.read_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file", sep='|')
```

Or if you wish to convert it from list of string instead:

```
data = [row.split('|') for row in X]
headers = data.pop(0) # Pop the first element since it's header
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

Comment: @NiraliKhoda could you mark if it works so it can be helpful to others?

Answer (score 1):

you had it almost correct actually, but don't use `data` as dictionary(by using keys - `data[x] = textnew`):

```
X = ["NAME|Contact|Education","SMITH|12345|Graduate","NITA|11111|Diploma"]
df = []

for i in X:
    df.append(i.split("|"))

print(df)

# [['NAME', 'Contact', 'Education'], ['SMITH', '12345', 'Graduate'], ['NITA', '11111', 'Diploma']]
```

Depends on further transformations, but pandas might be overkill for this kind of task

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your problem

```
import pandas as pd
X = ["NAME|Contact|Education","SMITH|12345|Graduate","NITA|11111|Diploma"]
data = []
for i in X:
    data.append( i.split("|") )
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=data.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you can avoid to load the file using `readlines` and use pandas for take care about loading the file:

As mentioned above, the solution is a standard `read_csv`:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
path = "/tmp"
filepath = "file.xls"
filename = os.path.join(path,filepath)
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|')
print(df.head)
```

---

Another approach (in such situation when you have no access to the file or you have to deal with a list of string) can be wrap the list of string as a text file, then load normally using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

X = ["NAME|Contact|Education", "SMITH|12345|Graduate", "NITA|11111|Diploma"]
# Wrap the string list as a file of new line
DATA = StringIO("\n".join(X))
# Load as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(DATA, delimiter="|")
```

Here the result

[image]